# How does the human eye form an image of a certain size at a certain distance?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, vision, perception

In looking at how geometric optics works and how an eye rebuilds an image of a certain size at a certain distance, some questions came to me:

[image]

Let's take a look at the first picture for example; the point of the four red arrows, with different size, produce the same point on the retina, B', this means that the point on the retina in which light arrives cannot determine the distance at which the brain reconstructs; if it did, for every image we see there would be infinite compatible images and we would see nothing.

This makes me think that the cones and rods that are hit by some rays of light "communicate" only three things to the brain: color, intensity, spot on the retina hit by the image.

This last thing should be related in some way to the size of the image: in fact, let's consider the second image,

[image]

the two arrows, same size, are reconstructed with different sizes: this accounts for the fact that we see distant objects, smaller.

**From the point where light hits the retina to image reconstruction, what does the brain do?**

If we consider a flat mirror, the image is reconstructed by the brain running through rays and forming a virtual image beyond the mirror, but isn't the point hitted by light on the retina compatible with infinite images? How does the brain know when to "stop"?

**Part three:**

[image]

The image we see, is the virtual image of height $h_i$ or the one formed on the retina?

**Maybe I'm getting confused by the image formed by the brain and the concept of image introduced by geometrical optics. I would also need clarification on this.**

Comment: Re, "How does the brain know when to "stop"?" You mean, how does it know the distance to the real object? The answer to that question isn't in the diagrams that you drew. You use other cues to infer the distance to objects in your field of vision. At long distances, it's mostly based on your past experience. E.g., People are all more or less the same size. You can get a rough estimate of the distance to a person just by how big they _appear_  to be in your field of view. Other cues include [_stereopsis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereopsis) and the effort required to focus your eyes.\*

Comment: \* That's if you're young. For oldsters like me, substitute which part of my tri-focal glasses I have to look through.

Comment: I must also add that your concept of how it is focused is not entirely right. Take your first image example. Only one of the arrows would be at focus at a time. You are drawing a single line. To know if an image would be formed you need to add at least a second  line parallel to the main axis (like img3). Then you would see that only one of the arrows would be properly imaged. To image the others, the eye needs to accommodate to another focal distance. Lastly, your question regarding how does the brain do imaging would be more appropriate to pyschology and neuroscience or biology SEs.